# Is there a way to fetch Hive table size in SSIS and store it in a variable?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, hive, hiveql

I have to fetch ***Hive tables size in GB*** (list of table names will be passed to argument one by one) irrespective of partitions, ***using SSIS package*** and store it in a variable .

While searching I came up with 'show tblproperties tableName' option to fetch table size and other table details .

Is there any other simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @jamesvasanth. The way I see it, you need to develop a standalone wrapper/API around the HDInsight .net SDK, or install the SDK and use the code as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-use-hive-dotnet-sdk in a Script Task.
Only then you can populate a SSIS variable.

Comment: Hi @Arthur. I am looking for simple way to achieve it, but this involves more effort I guess